# My State is not updating when i choose a different option from my Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I'm trying to do a picker where i loop over an array, and when i click on different workout exercises, it should update the text below which says "Selected exercise:" , but its stuck and not updating my view at all.

Here is my code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkoutView: View {
    
    var workouts: [WorkoutPlan] = [
        .init(name: "Hyper Up", setsReps: "4 x 10-12 reps", weight: "low/mid weights", imageName: "arrow.up", bodyPart: "Up"),
        .init(name: "Heavy Up", setsReps: "5 x 3-5 reps", weight: "heavy weights", imageName: "chevron.up",bodyPart: "Up"),
        .init(name: "Hyper Down", setsReps: "4 x 10-12 reps", weight: "low/mid weights",imageName: "arrow.down",bodyPart: "Down"),
        .init(name: "Heavy Down", setsReps: "5 x 3-5 reps", weight: "heavy weights",imageName: "chevron.down",bodyPart: "Down")
    ]
    
    @State var selectedExercise: String?
    
    
    var body: some View{
        
        NavigationStack{
            List{
                Section(){
                    ForEach(workouts, id: \.name) {
                        workout in
                        NavigationLink(value:workout) {Label(workout.name, systemImage: workout.imageName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Workout Plans")
            .navigationDestination(for: WorkoutPlan.self) {workout in
                //own screen should come here
                let exercises: [Exercise] = [
                    .init(name: "Dumbbell Shoulder Press", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Over Head Press", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Bench Press", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Butterfly", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Incline Bench Press", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Triceps Cable Row", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "Biceps Curl", bodyPart: "Up"),
                    .init(name: "ABS Cable Curl", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Plank", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Deadlift", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Seated Cable Row", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Squat", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Sumo Deadlift", bodyPart: "Down"),
                    .init(name: "Front Squat", bodyPart: "Down"),
                ]
                let upExercises = exercises.filter { $0.bodyPart == "Up" }
                let downExercises = exercises.filter { $0.bodyPart == "Down" }
                
                ZStack {
                        VStack{
                            List{
                                Section(){
                                    if workout.bodyPart == "Up" {
                                        
                                        Label(workout.name, systemImage: workout.imageName).font(.largeTitle).bold()
                                        VStack{

                                            Picker(
                                                selection: $selectedExercise,
                                                label: Text("Workout"),
                                                content: {
                                                    ForEach(upExercises, id: \.self) { exercise in
                                                        HStack{
                                                            Text(exercise.name).tag(exercise.name)
                                                        }
                                                    }}
                                            ).pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                                            Text("Selected exercise: \(selectedExercise ?? "No exercise selected")")
                                        }
                                    } else if workout.bodyPart == "Down" {
                                        Label(workout.name, systemImage: workout.imageName).font(.largeTitle).bold()
                                        ForEach(downExercises.suffix(7), id: \.name) { exercise in
                                            Text(exercise.name)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    
                }.accentColor(Color(.label))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct WorkoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View{
        WorkoutView()
    }
}

struct WorkoutPlan: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let setsReps: String
    let weight: String
    let imageName: String
    let bodyPart: String
}

struct Exercise: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let bodyPart: String
}
```

I have tried to move around the State as i thougth it might be off the scope,i have tried to convert .tag to String? but that also didnt work. I have looked through Stack and google but couldn't find anything that could fix my problem.